# how to valid there is no attribute "checked" in xhtml 1.0 validation

Tags: validation, xhtml

i have use

```
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('none', 60)" checked="checked">Default style</a>
```

for style sheet switch but this code is not valid and i have error in http://validator.w3.org

how i can fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

simple, take out the `checked='checked'` out of your a tag. It's not a valid attribute for an 'a' tag in either xhtml strict or transitional

you'll have to come up with another way to store the style sheetswitch. possibly storing your `checked` option in the class instead, and checking that the class contains 'checked'.